# How to keep a conditional Running Value MS Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to use Reporting Services to create a report displaying the call activity of various sales reps.  The report will group by extension and then date of call.  For each group of call dates (that is, all the calls for a particular date), I want to display some totals.  One of the totals I want to display is the total number of calls whose duration greater than 2 minutes.  I can see how to use the RunningValue function to keep a running total of ALL calls for the date, but I'm not sure how to make that conditional on the length of call.  Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:  The checked answer below did it... I used a case statement in linq like this:

```
            var qry = from Q in c.CallList
                  select new
                  {
                      Q.Extension,
                      Q.CallDate,
                      Q.Duration
                      CallCountOverTwoMinutes = Q.duration > 120 ? 1 : 0,                          
                  };
```

Then I sum the value of CallCountOverTwoMinutes.  Thanks for the help, Chris!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to pass the value as part of the dataset. For example, using SQL:

```
SELECT Extension, CallDate, Duration, 
    CASE WHEN Duration > 2 THEN 1 END AS CallsOver2Mins
FROM CallTable
```

Then just sum on CallsOver2Mins.